# Active MQ 5.10.0 message re-delivery policy not working

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I have never worked with activeMQ's before. I am doing some research for my project where I need to redeliver the message according to listeners logic. As per [activemq's documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html), I am:

1. Using Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE mode
2. Depending on the logic, acknowledging message or doing session.recover to get the message again.

Using my current code I am able to read messages off the testQueue once. 
But my re-delivery policies arn't working. I tried settign an initial delay but the message is delivered automatically. I wan the message to be redelivered 5 times. Thats not happening.

I am creating a connection factory, connection, session and a queue using following code:

```
    RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
    redeliveryPolicy.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(0);
    redeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(5);
    redeliveryPolicy.setRedeliveryDelay(1000);
    redeliveryPolicy.setQueue("*");
    redeliveryPolicy.setBackOffMultiplier(2);

    factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);     
    factory.setRedeliveryPolicy(redeliveryPolicy);

    connection = (ActiveMQConnection) factory.createConnection();       
    // connection.setRedeliveryPolicy(redeliveryPolicy);

    connection.start();
    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    String queueName = "testQueue"+(UUID.randomUUID());
    System.out.println("Creating Queue: "+queueName);
    testQueue = session.createQueue(queueName);
```

I tried setting the RedeliveryPolicy to ActiveMQConnectionFactory and ActiveMQConnection both (didnt work for me.)

I am then in a consumer doing following to set Message Listener:

```
MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(testQueue);
consumer.setMessageListener(new MyMessageListener(id, session));
```

MyMessageListener:

```
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
            String text = textMessage.getText();
            System.out.println("Consuming["+threadId+"] message: " + text);


            if(text.contains("RD")){
                System.out.println("acknowledgeThisMessage");
                ((com.sun.messaging.jms.Message)message).acknowledgeThisMessage();
            } else{
                session.recover();
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Consuming["+threadId+"] Weird Message: " + message);
        }
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If you need any more information, let me know I can update the post. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get RedeliveryPolicies to work correctly if I create the listener inside consumer. I am not sure why this works and making a seperate class doesn't. My consumer now looks like:

```
try {           
        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(testQueue);
        consumer.setMessageListener(new MessageListener() {
            public void onMessage(Message message) {
                try {
                    if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                        TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                        String text = textMessage.getText();
                        System.out.println("Consuming["+threadId+"] message: " + text);

                        if(text.contains("RD")){
                            System.out.println("acknowledgeThisMessage");
                            ((com.sun.messaging.jms.Message)message).acknowledgeThisMessage();
                        } else{
                            System.out.println("recovering the message");
                            session.recover();
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Consuming["+threadId+"] Weird Message: " + message);
                    }
                } catch (JMSException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Hope this helps someone.